# How can I merge the settings and documents from an account on Windows XP to the Admin account?

Tags: windows-xp, migration, user-settings

experts and pros...
I would like to "migrate" or "merge" an account on my Windows XP computer to/with the Admin account, till now unactivated.
The reason I don't want to simply activate and copy the stuff is because I use very specific applications and pathes that I would like to preserve the way they are.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used "[User Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html)". It works fine.

Comment: I just used it. Simple and good, just the way I like a software... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe NTFS junction points or hardlinks will do the trick here 's a gui tool for that purpose:
[hardlinkshell utility](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)

Comment: Ok, I'm trying it right away. It looks like it's working fine... for now! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows already has a solution for you. In System properties you can simply copy a profile to another account.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Files and Settings Transfer Wizard before. Works about as good as Microsoft could manage (works great 90% of the time). Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools.

Comment: No, it's actually on the same machine. I think the Windows tool can only deal with two separate Windows installation, am I wrong?